# How to add value to select tag from input field?

Tags: javascript

How to add value to select tag from input field?
When I text something to input field that named add_val
and click the button, it will add the value to select tag option.

```
<form>
  <select id="mySelect" size="8">
    <option>Apple</option>
    <option>Pear</option>
    <option>Banana</option>
    <option>Orange</option>
  </select>
</form>
 <br>   
<input type="text" id="add_val" name="add_val">   
<button type="button" onclick="myFunction()">Insert option</button>

<script>
function myFunction() {
  var addvar = document.getElementById("add_val").value;  
  var x = document.getElementById("mySelect");
  var option = document.createElement("option");
  x.add(addvar);

}
</script>
```

But finally, it doesn't work, anyidea, thank you very much

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use [appendChild](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/appendChild) Js function and also assign a value and [innerHTML](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML) to your newly option created option.

You can either use `.text` `.textContent` to you new option as well.

Run snippet below to see it working.

```js
function myFunction() {
  var addvar = document.getElementById("add_val").value;
  var select = document.getElementById("mySelect")
  var x = document.getElementById("mySelect");
  var option = document.createElement("option");
  option.value = addvar;
  option.textContent = addvar;
  select.appendChild(option);
  //Clear Input
  document.getElementById("add_val").value = '';
}
```

```html
<form>
  <select id="mySelect" size="8">
    <option>Apple</option>
    <option>Pear</option>
    <option>Banana</option>
    <option>Orange</option>
  </select>
</form>

<input type="text" id="add_val" name="add_val">
<button type="button" onclick="myFunction()">Insert option</button>
```

Comment: Nailed it. Gotta love appendChild.

Comment: Use `.text`, `.innerText` or `.textContent` to set the content. DOM elements are not permitted to be a child of an `option` element, so using an HTML parser, like `.innerHTML`, is misleading.

Comment: @slappy Yes i am aware i have added more info to the answer to reflect that as well. Thanks for your comment.

Answer (score 1):

what you are doing is wrong, so the correct code is:

```js
function myFunction() {
  var select = document.getElementById('mySelect');
  var option = document.createElement('option')
  // get the value from the input
  var text = document.getElementById('add_val').value;
  // create text node for option element
  option.appendChild(document.createTextNode(text));
  // set option value
  option.value = text;
  // add option to select
  select.appendChild(option);
}
```

```html
<form>
  <select id="mySelect" size="8">
    <option>Apple</option>
    <option>Pear</option>
    <option>Banana</option>
    <option>Orange</option>
  </select>
</form>
 <br>   
<input type="text" id="add_val" name="add_val">   
<button type="button" onclick="myFunction()">Insert option</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Can be done with less lines;

```
function myFunction() {
  var x = document.getElementById("mySelect");
  var option = document.createElement("option");
  option.text = document.getElementById("add_val").value;
  x.add(option);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `.insertAdjacentHTML()` with string interpolation to make it short and easy.

```js
function myFunction() {
  var addvar = document.getElementById("add_val").value;
  document.getElementById("mySelect")
    .insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend", `<option>${addvar}</option>`);

}
```

```html
<form>
  <select id="mySelect" size="8">
    <option>Apple</option>
    <option>Pear</option>
    <option>Banana</option>
    <option>Orange</option>
  </select>
</form>
<br>
<input type="text" id="add_val" name="add_val">
<button type="button" onclick="myFunction()">Insert option</button>
```

---

but if you want to create the DOM element directly, I'd do it like this:

```js
function myFunction() {
  document.getElementById("mySelect")
    .appendChild(document.createElement("option"))
    .text = document.getElementById("add_val").value;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <select id="mySelect" size="8">
    <option>Apple</option>
    <option>Pear</option>
    <option>Banana</option>
    <option>Orange</option>
  </select>
</form>
<br>
<input type="text" id="add_val" name="add_val">
<button type="button" onclick="myFunction()">Insert option</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

This does has a function that does it `onkeyup` and and `onclick`. I used the `appendChild` function.

```js
function myFunction1() {

  var val = $("#add_val1").val();
  var select = document.getElementById("mySelect");
  var option = document.createElement("option");
  option.value = val;
  option.textContent = val;
  select.appendChild(option);

}

function myFunction2() {

  var val = $("#add_val1").val();
  var select = document.getElementById("mySelect");
  var option = document.createElement("option");
  option.value = val;
  option.textContent = val;
  select.appendChild(option);

}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <select id="mySelect" size="8">
    <option>Apple</option>
    <option>Pear</option>
    <option>Banana</option>
    <option>Orange</option>
  </select>
</form>
 <br>
 
<h5>To Add Value Onkeyup</h5>
<input type="text" id="add_val1" name="add_val1" onkeyup="myFunction1()">

<h5>To Add Value When Button Is Clicked</h5>
<input type="text" id="add_val2" name="add_val2">
<button onclick="myFunction2()">Insert Option</button>
```